# k3s - getting credentials: exec: executable kubectl-oidc_login not found

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, k3s

On the [k3s.io - Quick-Start - Install Script](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s#quick-start---install-script) page suggested running the command:

```
sudo kubectl get nodes
```

But I get a long error message:

```
sudo kubectl get nodes
E1221 10:50:43.569709   17813 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://api.eb3e7bb.kyma.ondemand.com/api?timeout=32s": getting credentials: exec: executable kubectl-oidc_login not found

It looks like you are trying to use a client-go credential plugin that is not installed.

To learn more about this feature, consult the documentation available at:
      https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins

kubelogin plugin is required to proceed with authentication
# Homebrew (macOS and Linux)
brew install int128/kubelogin/kubelogin

# Krew (macOS, Linux, Windows and ARM)
kubectl krew install oidc-login

# Chocolatey (Windows)
choco install kubelogin
E1221 10:50:43.569954   17813 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://api.eb3e7bb.kyma.ondemand.com/api?timeout=32s": getting credentials: exec: executable kubectl-oidc_login not found

It looks like you are trying to use a client-go credential plugin that is not installed.

To learn more about this feature, consult the documentation available at:
      https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins

kubelogin plugin is required to proceed with authentication
# Homebrew (macOS and Linux)
brew install int128/kubelogin/kubelogin

# Krew (macOS, Linux, Windows and ARM)
kubectl krew install oidc-login

# Chocolatey (Windows)
choco install kubelogin
E1221 10:50:43.571310   17813 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://api.eb3e7bb.kyma.ondemand.com/api?timeout=32s": getting credentials: exec: executable kubectl-oidc_login not found

It looks like you are trying to use a client-go credential plugin that is not installed.

To learn more about this feature, consult the documentation available at:
      https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins

kubelogin plugin is required to proceed with authentication
# Homebrew (macOS and Linux)
brew install int128/kubelogin/kubelogin

# Krew (macOS, Linux, Windows and ARM)
kubectl krew install oidc-login

# Chocolatey (Windows)
choco install kubelogin
E1221 10:50:43.571484   17813 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://api.eb3e7bb.kyma.ondemand.com/api?timeout=32s": getting credentials: exec: executable kubectl-oidc_login not found

It looks like you are trying to use a client-go credential plugin that is not installed.

To learn more about this feature, consult the documentation available at:
      https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins

kubelogin plugin is required to proceed with authentication
# Homebrew (macOS and Linux)
brew install int128/kubelogin/kubelogin

# Krew (macOS, Linux, Windows and ARM)
kubectl krew install oidc-login

# Chocolatey (Windows)
choco install kubelogin
E1221 10:50:43.572779   17813 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://api.eb3e7bb.kyma.ondemand.com/api?timeout=32s": getting credentials: exec: executable kubectl-oidc_login not found

It looks like you are trying to use a client-go credential plugin that is not installed.

To learn more about this feature, consult the documentation available at:
      https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins

kubelogin plugin is required to proceed with authentication
# Homebrew (macOS and Linux)
brew install int128/kubelogin/kubelogin

# Krew (macOS, Linux, Windows and ARM)
kubectl krew install oidc-login

# Chocolatey (Windows)
choco install kubelogin
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable kubectl-oidc_login not found

It looks like you are trying to use a client-go credential plugin that is not installed.

To learn more about this feature, consult the documentation available at:
      https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins

kubelogin plugin is required to proceed with authentication
# Homebrew (macOS and Linux)
brew install int128/kubelogin/kubelogin

# Krew (macOS, Linux, Windows and ARM)
kubectl krew install oidc-login

# Chocolatey (Windows)
choco install kubelogin
```

It feels like one message is **duplicated 3 times**, it’s unclear why.

Let's take a look. The first message reads:

```
It looks like you are trying to use a client-go credential plugin that is not installed.
```

And as a solution, it is proposed to install the `kubelogin plugin` in three different ways to choose from. So I use `Ubuntu`, let's look at the options for `Ubuntu`:

```
# 1 - Homebrew (macOS and Linux)
brew install int128/kubelogin/kubelogin

# 2 - Krew (macOS, Linux, Windows and ARM)
kubectl krew install oidc-login
```

However, I have already installed `brew install int128/kubelogin/kubelogin`, as evidenced by the logs in the terminal:

```
$ brew install int128/kubelogin/kubelogin
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
==> Homebrew collects anonymous analytics.
Read the analytics documentation (and how to opt-out) here:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Analytics
No analytics have been recorded yet (nor will be during this `brew` run).

==> Homebrew is run entirely by unpaid volunteers. Please consider donating:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/brew#donations

Warning: int128/kubelogin/kubelogin v1.28.0 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall v1.28.0, run:
  brew reinstall kubelogin
```

And just in case I installed `oidc-login` using command `kubectl krew install oidc-login`, because `oidc-login` and `int128/kubelogin/kubelogin` have different names and I believe that these are generally different plugins, so I installed everything:

```
$ kubectl krew install oidc-login
Updated the local copy of plugin index.
Installing plugin: oidc-login
W1221 10:56:54.420669   19454 install.go:160] Skipping plugin "oidc-login", it is already installed
```

As we can see, both `int128/kubelogin/kubelogin` and `oidc-login` are **already installed**, but after running the `sudo kubectl get nodes` command, I still get the long error above.

Why and how is this solved?